# Eigenvectors and Invariant Sets

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, invariant-subspace

Consider a system $\dot x=Ax$ 
Suppose $A\nu = \lambda\nu,\, \nu\ne0,\,\lambda\in \Bbb R$ 
Then how do I show that the line $\{ t\nu\,|\,t\in\Bbb R\}$ is invariant?

Comment: Why the (dynamical-systems) tag? Are you looking at the ODE $dx/dt=Ax$, by any chance? If so, you should perhaps mention that in the question...

Comment: Yes. I am. I have made the edits. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $x(t) = C e^{\lambda t} \nu$ satisfies the ODE.

Comment: Yes, I got till that. But I don't know how to prove invariance sets. I am new to the concept.

Comment: Well, do you know the definition of “invariant” to begin with? Once you've gotten this far, the result ought to be almost obvious.

Comment: Yes, I was able to prove it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = t \nu$. Then, $Ax = (A)(t\nu) = t(A)(\nu) = t\lambda \nu \in \{t \nu \mid t \in \Bbb R\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x(0) = tv,\,v$ is an eigenvector of the system $\dot x = Ax, \, t\in\Bbb R$ 
Therefore, $tv$ is also and eigenvector of $A$
$x(t)=e^{\lambda t}tv$ (Solution of $\dot x = Ax$ with $t_0=0,\, x(t_0) = tv$)
$x(t)=(te^{\lambda t})v$
$x(t)=Tv,\,T=te^{\lambda t},\,T\in\Bbb R$
So, for all $t>t_0,\,x(t)$ lies in the set.